# formatting indentation in a reference text

Tags: cross-referencing

I made a document in word and then in a rush I had to change it to Latex, I do not have time to use the bibtex for my references, so I just copy and paste them from word. The problem that I got is that my references are appearing like this:

[image]

but I would like them to appear like this:

[image]

I am a newbie in latex, so I would like to know how can I do to move the [] to the left and indent the text to the right, so that it appears like the model that I want it to be.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thanks for the link, but the problem that I got now is that it appears a white line between one reference and another, how I can get rid of it?

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}, parsep=0pt]` or any other value. There are many posts on this topic on this site. Please use the query function in the top right corner.